# How to decode QR code with ZXing on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have a University project which involves QR code recognition and generation. I've looked at both an Arduino and Raspberry Pi, but in my research I found that the Pi is better for image decoding due to memory constraints on the Arduino (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

My question is: how do I use ZXing to decode the image with a Pi? I've read about people flashing their Pi's with Android and going on from there, but I'd like to avoid that seeing as I'd might like to expand on the project without Android in the way.

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489048/qr-code-encoding-and-decoding-using-zxing

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22871/software-to-read-a-qr-code

Comment: Also appears relevant:http://lifehacker.com/5756268/zbar-brings-barcode-and-qr-code-scanning-to-your-desktop

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797924/decoding-colored-image-using-zxing-library-in-java

Comment: Alternitively:  http://ralgozino.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/how-to-create-and-decode-a-qr-code-in-python-using-qrtools/